# Python-extract list with better score

Tags: python, sorting

Hi I am working on this assignment.

I want to extract exactly a half of the list with better score (the smaller the better).
For example :

```
s=[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3,[3,1,2],[3,2,1],[2,3,1]]
```

The corresponding score of list s is

```
score=[13,14,24,28,17,17]
```

My desire output is :
ss should contain only 3

```
ss =[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1]]
```

or 
`ss =[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,3,1]]`. Because the last two lists have the same score

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What is the logic behind scoring lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
[i for i, j in sorted(zip(s, score), key=lambda x: x[1])[:3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you may perform below steps:

1. Sort the list of `scores` in ascending order and get the lowest `n` scores
2. Fetch element from `s` list based on the index of occurrence of `n` smallest numbers in the `scores` list

Below is the sample code to achieve it via using *list comprehension* and `list.index(..)` method (steps are mentioned as comment):

```
>>> s=[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[3,1,2],[3,2,1],[2,3,1]]
>>> score=[13,14,24,28,17,17]
>>> smallest_num_count = 3  # count of desired numbers

# Get lowest three scores          v slice list from the start
>>> smallest_scores = sorted(score)[:smallest_num_count]
#                      ^ sorts the `score` list in ascending order

#              v returns index of the first occurrence of the 
#              v    `i` element in `score` lsit
>>> [s[score.index(i)] for i in smallest_scores]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```